# Manipulating user uploaded data for ggplot - Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am trying to create a Shiny app that takes data uploaded by the user and creates plots from the data.

Using this code, the file uploads and you can view it using `print(head(df))`. The plot, however, appears blank with labels on the x and y axes and a title, but no data. I want to create multiple plots with the data, too. Would I put the plot codes in succession in the observe statement?

```
server <- function(input, output) {

observe({
    file1=input$file1
    if (is.null(file1)){
      return(NULL)
    }
    df<-read.csv(file1$datapath)
    df$FAIL<-ifelse(df$OPERATION_STATUS %in% "FAIL",1,0)

    output$env<-renderPlot({
        e <- df[which(df$CATEGORY %in% "OSV-ENVIRONMENT" & df$FAIL == 1),]
        p <- ggplot(e, aes(DATE, CRIT_CODE, color=as.factor(FAIL))) +
            geom_point(size=3) +
            labs(title="Environment Fails by Date") +
            theme_light() +
            theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5))
        print(p)
    })
})
```

Comment: Are you sure that the file is being uploaded properly? If not, you can test by putting `print(head(df))` (if local) or `shinyjs::logjs(head(df))` (if on server) after `df <- read.csv(...)`

Comment: @divibisan yes, the file uploads and you can view it using print(head(df))

Comment: @Lost it works for me. Try check **e** if it is subset correctly and contains data.